# uWSGI with nginx bad gateway error

Tags: nginx, django, uwsgi

So I'm trying to host my django app with nginx and uwsgi but i keep running into a 502 bad gateway error. I have the following nginx config.

```
    upstream django {
    server unix:///home/david/fimetsu_2/fimetsu-django/fimetsu.sock;
}
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name fimetsu.com www.fimetsu.com;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;
    location /media  {
        alias /home/david/fimetsu_2/fimetsu-django/media;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /home/david/fimetsu_2/fimetsu-django/theme/static;
    }
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/david/fimetsu_2/fimetsu-django/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

I use the following uWSGI command to serve the website
`uwsgi --socket fimetsu.sock --module fimetsu.wsgi --chmod-socket=664` (also tried 666 permission)
this is my uwsgi logs

```
** Starting uWSGI 2.0.20 (64bit) on [Sun Jan 28 11:39:00 2024] ***
compiled with version: 11.4.0 on 27 January 2024 17:23:25
os: Linux-5.15.0-1030-aws #34-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 23 20:13:32 UTC 2023
nodename: ip-172-26-14-147
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/david/fimetsu_2/fimetsu-django
detected binary path: /home/david/fimetsu_2/venv/bin/uwsgi
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 7837
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address fimetsu.sock fd 3
Python version: 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x55a24e5cc020
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72920 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x55a24e5cc020 pid: 1074682 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 1074682, cores: 1)
```

so when i go to [www.fimetsu.com:8000/home](http://www.fimetsu.com:8000/home) all is fine but when i go to [www.fimetsu.com/home](http://www.fimetsu.com/home) i get the 502 bad gateway error. I look forward to everyones ideas and help!

Comment: Check your `nginx` logs.